# laravel4 add checkbox column in database using migration file

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel4 to develop one of my project.I have a migration file where i want to add unchecked or by default a false checkbox colummn to add approval functionality for admin.So my question is very simple ,that is how to add a unchecked checkbox column in a migration file.

here is my marriage migration file,

```
Schema::create('marriages', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        ------------------------ // field for unchecked checkbox column
        $table->string('candidate_name',255)->unique();
        $table->string('email',255)->unique();
        $table->string('father_name',60);
        $table->string('mother_name',60);
        $table->date('date_of_birth');
        $table->string('sex',60);
        $table->string('location',255);
        $table->string('blood_group',20);
        $table->string('religion',60);
        $table->string('present_address',255);
        $table->string('permanent_address',60);
        $table->string('height',100)->nullable();
        $table->string('complexion',100);
        $table->string('nationality',100);
        $table->string('educational_qualification',255);
        $table->string('occupation',255);
        $table->integer('phone_number');
        $table->integer('number_of_bro_sis');
        $table->string('image',255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Update:**

now how can i check it in my template,i want to show those results from this field which is actually  approved ,should i use

```
@if($results->approved(true))
  then show the results object
```

or  should i use some thing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "checkbox" column. You are probably talking about a boolean, which is technically speaking a tinyint (assuming you use MySQL)

Here's how you add one:

```
$table->boolean('approved');
```

usually the default should be `false` now, but to make sure:

```
$table->boolean('approved')->default(false);
```

Here's the [full reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns) of all schema builder column methods

---

#### About your edit

If you would want to use `$results->approved(true)` or `$results->approved()` you would have to add a custom function to your model.

However you can do it much simpler

```
@if($results->approved == true)
```

Or even omit `== true` because the if will check for a "truthy" value

```
@if($results->approved)
```

Comment: thannks for your answer,its working,i am going to accept it very soon.if i ask any  extented question related to this,can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Great! Sure I can try my best :)

Comment: Okay. But if it's too far off-topic of this question you'll be better off asking a new one...

Comment: please see the post above,i have updated my question,its not too far away from the topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66854/discussion-between-rego-and-lukasgeiter).

Comment: i have do it according to your answer that is i have used the @if($result->approved) ... but now i am facing the error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$approved